# (Log) Concavity of a simple equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Consider the function 
$$
f(x)=\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}\right)\left(1-\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{x_{j}}{1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_{ij}x_{i}}\right)
$$
where $0\leq x_i\leq 1$ and $0\leq A_{ij}\leq 1$. Assume also the the second parenthesis is always positive.

I'm interested in the concavity of this function. In particular, what additional conditions (if any) must be imposed on $A$ to insure the log concavity of $f$? Of course, $A_{ij}=0$ works. It seems that $f$ is also log concave if $A_{ij}=c$ where $c$ is some constant. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "Concavity of a simple equation" - well, for many it isn't simple.

Comment: I would focus solely on the second term. The first term is trivially log-concave, so if you can prove the second term is as well, you're done.

Comment: The issue is that often the second term is not log-concave but the whole thing is!

Comment: Interesting. Where are you seeing that?

Comment: For instance if you type "plot log(1-x/(1+x+y)-y/(1+x+y))" (the second term in 2D with A=1) it is clearly not concave but if you add the first term "log(x+y)" then we have concavity.